# grepping large amounts of text

Tags: linux, unix, performance, grep

I have a few gigabytes of source code.

using recursive grep for a term can take a while.

I am using ext3.

Is there a faster way? Would using find be faster and if so why? Would using a filesystem like XFS give noticeably better results?

Comment: with exec it can use grep which would be faster than just using grep

Comment: and why would that be faster?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/)? It works pretty well here, on a 1mm+ sized codebase.

Comment: ack is easier and faster than using find | grep, and I often use it, but it doesn't index the results anywhere for later use.

Answer (score 3):

You can get better performance with agrep, which uses a novel bitmasking algorithm for search.

If you're looking for symbols, ctags or etags might work well enough to build an index for search.

Comment: Ctags indexes the results, so you can search quickly from your editor. Darren Hiebert's Exuberant Ctags (ctags.sourceforge.net) has improved options for recursive searching.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you'll get a significant improvement over grep is to use an indexed search system like [Strigi](http://strigi.sourceforge.net/).  The filesystem makes very little difference unless you have a huge number of very small files.

Answer (score 1):

*This should likely be on superuser.*

Grepping is **not** the ideal solution to your problem since it performs a linear search.

Index your files for search using a desktop indexing solution such as [Beagle](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page) or [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/linux/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the FS is going to make a big difference; chances are it's compute bound. You could check this using `top` to see if your CPUs are smoking.

You could also post your regexp here and let the smart people of SO have a crack at optimizing it. There are a variety of techniques for avoiding backtracking, etc.

Comment: `fgrep` is faster because it doesn't use regular expressions, it only searches for fixed strings.  It's just an alias for `grep -F`.

Comment: Right you are, thanks. I removed that part of my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to grep a subset of files then use find first. For example to only grep .h header files:

```
find path/to/source -name *.h -print0 | xargs -0 grep pattern
```

This will be faster since you're only accessing filenames most of the time, rather than file contents, which means many fewer disc accesses.

Comment: Better: `find path/to/source -name *.h -exec grep pattern {} \;`

Comment: Even better: `find path/to/source -name *.h -exec grep pattern {} \+` (less `grep` invocations)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I understand -

- You are searching source code for a term
- You'd like to see which source files use that term
- You probably have thousands of files (adding up to GBs)
- Do you want to know all the occurrences of 'term' within each file or a yes/no indication of whether its been used in a file or not? (the -l flag does this).

You can use the policy of divide-and-rule. Partition your set into multiple file-sets, run multiple greps parallely.

Not sure if your need is a one-off thing or something repetitive in nature.